# Linq, exclude SQL Nulls

Tags: c#, linq

I'm generating a pie chart, currently I have  have the following variable, How to exclude Null records? it works but it  includes null values in the pie chart

```
var PieChartData1 = from T1 in Result
                    group T1 by T1.Reasons  into G1
                    orderby count ascending
                    select new { G1.Key, Count = G1.Count()  };
```

---

```
 obj.peichart1 = PieChartData1.ToArray();
```

Comment: Add a Where clause to filter out Nulls

Comment: where Reasons  != null ... i get an error (  Reasons   does not exist in current context)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `where T1.Reasons != null`?

Comment: @Rufus L That worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `where` clause to filter the `null` values before you use them - here I'm assuming that either `T1` or `T1.Reasons` can be `null`:

```
var PieChartData1 = from T1 in Result
                        where T1 != null && T1.Reasons != null
                        group T1 by T1.Reasons into G1
                        orderby count ascending
                        select new { G1.Key, Count = G1.Count() };
```

I also suspect that `orderby count ascending` should be `orderby G1.Count() ascending`.

Comment: Thank you! I actually went with >> where T1.Reason != null

Answer (score 2):

if T1 is Nullable use HasValue Property

```
var PieChartData1 = from T1 in Result
                        where T1.HasValue
                        group T1 by T1.Reasons into G1
                        orderby count ascending
                        select new { G1.Key, Count = G1.Count() };
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually went with >> where T1.Reason != null    ...>>  where T1.HasValue() seemed to not work

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it using lambda expressions:

```
var pieChartData = Result.Where(r => r.Reason != null)
                         .GroupBy(r => r.Reason)
                         .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
                         .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```